# Dropbox Webhooks API

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to fetch the events related to my dropbox like I can see [here](https://www.dropbox.com/events) , means I want to get when a particular file is added, changed, moved, deleted or renamed and by which user.

I have looked into the [Webhooks docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/webhooks/tutorial). The webhook docs states the the response it sends to the callback url contails the userids, with which I can update the directory listing based on the webhook response for the user by calling the /delta.

But with it I cannot tell if there is an operation made for a file like a particular file has been renamed or deleted as since if I rename a file fro abc to xyz. If I get a response then I will look for the changes related to the file xyz which I will not find in my existing database so logically I will be making the events as deleted abc and added xyz, where as the reality is renamed abc to xyz.

It will be really grateful if you can help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real way to detect a rename (versus a delete and an add) via the Dropbox API. You can use heuristics (like whether the new file has the same contents as the old file and was created around the same time as the old file was deleted), but those are just going to be guesses with varying levels of accuracy.

Also, there's currently no way via the API to see which user modified a file in a shared folder.

**UPDATE**: The Core API now includes (in beta) the ability to see who last modified a file in a shared folder. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/101/new-in-beta-shared-folder-metadata.

Comment: Are you from the Dropbox team, if yes then are you planning to open an API for Events soon .

Comment: I do work at Dropbox, and we just rolled out a beta of this functionality today. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks smarx for rolling out the API so quick and I can see the extra information that you have provided with it.

Answer (score 0):

A file rename is reported as `DeletedMetadata` followed by a `FileMetadata` for the file.

What is annoying is that `DeletedMetadata` do **not** contain the file `.id` attribute, only `.name` and `.path`, while `FileMetadata` include all attributes (`.id` same as before any deletions/renames, updated `.name` and `.path`).
So you should have a local mapping connecting names/paths and IDs in order to know which file got deleted (when only `DeletedMetadata` is received) or renamed (when both `DeletedMetadata` and `FileMetadata` are received).